# How to create my own .then() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently learning alot more about callback functions and want to create my own callback functions with a success and failure.

I have written for a `Person` object a game of rock paper sissors

```
Person = (function() {
  function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  Person.prototype.randomRps = function() {
    var choices, randomChoice;
    choices = ["rock", "paper", "sissor"];
    return randomChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  };

  Person.rockPaperSissor = function(player1, player2) {
    return player1.randomRps() === player2.randomRps();
  };

  return Person;

})();
```

I want to call `Person.rockPaperSissor(p1,p2).then(...)` but don't know how I should write this `.then()` function to chain it to the `.rockPaperSissor()`

Similar to how jQuery has `$.get()` and a `.success()` and `error()` functions to chain.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want is a Promise Implementation. If you are comfortable using a feature that isn't available in all browsers, you can use the native Promise implementation that is available on some modern browsers.

Comment: You don't have any asynchrony; there is no reason to do that.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://schier.co/post/method-chaining-in-javascript

Comment: @SLaks agreed - I was asking this for the sake of simplicity but it'd be in the context of async.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy - probably worth mocking that up in the question, otherwise the answers won't meet what you're interested in.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to return **this** at your function

```
Person.rockPaperSissor = function(player1, player2) {
    this.state = player1.randomRps() === player2.randomRps();
    return this;
};

Person.then = function() {
    var x = this.state;
};
```

Comment: Awesome! This works great! What if I don't want to do a `then` but instead want to do a `same(...)` or `different(...)` ? Would I just do an `if` statement to check?

Comment: Unfortunately this is beyond my knowledge, I'm sorry. But I saw that @nrabinowitz gave a fuller explanation about promisses

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that something in `Person.rockPaperSissor` is async**, you need to return some sort of Promise object. As others have noted, if the result here is synchronous, then there's no point in this particular misdirection. JQuery provides an implementation in [DeferredObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/); if you want to write your own, you'd need to work out what methods this object should support.

To take a relatively simple case, you could make a Promise class that only supported `.then` like this:

```
function Promise() {
    // start unresolved
    this.resolved = false;
    // init list of callbacks to fire on resolution
    this.callbacks = [];
}

Promise.prototype = {
    then: function(callback) {
        if (this.resolved) {
            // if resolved, fire immediately
            callback();
        } else {
            // otherwise, queue up the callback for later
            this.callbacks.push(callback);
        }
    },

    resolve: function() {
        this.resolved = true;
        // fire all callbacks
        this.callbacks.forEach(function(callback) {
            callback();
        });
    }
};
```

Then, in your async function, you'd do something like:

```
Person.rockPaperSissor = function(player1, player2) {
    var promise = new Promise();

    doSomethingAsync(function callback() {
        promise.resolve();
    });

    return promise;
};
```

In your specific case, `.then` won't be super-useful unless you expose the results of the `rockPaperSissor` function as persistent state on `Person`; if you want to pass the result to the callbacks, you'll need slightly more involved handling to pass arguments to your callbacks and potentially handle failure cases.

Comment: Thanks for that @nrabinowitz I didn't know how promises work but this is a great explanation to it.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation too @nrabinowitz, I did'n know how promisses works